# Create a query filter?

Tags: mysql

I need to query my database with filters, the user will select color, size and type. Each of these is represented by an int for faster look up.

So on the users form the colour red's value will be 1, blue will be 2 etc.

Here's my database structure:

Clothes

```
id | title | color | size | type
 1   jacket   1       2       1
```

I then query this:

```
SELECT * FROM clothes WHERE color IN (1,2) AND size IN (3,5) AND type IN (8,10)
```

My question is, does the multiple where in's slow performance, could I change my database structure and would that give better performance.

So change the Clothes table to

```
id | title
 1   jacket
```

Have a categories table that stores all possible categories no matter what type of category they are - mixing colours with sizes for example:

```
id | category
 1   red
 2   blue
 3   small
 4   large
 5   funky
 6   classic
```

Like these with a pivot:

```
id | clothes_id | category_id
1        1             2
2        1             4
3        2             1
```

And use a joining query on this?

Which would be the better method performance wise?

Comment: You only have to say WHERE once.

Comment: No. With appropriate indexes, I doubt it will make any difference for this kind of data. On a very, very large dataset, I suspect your existing model will be very, very slightly more efficient.